# Do apps deployed to xxx.herokuapp.com get crawled by google?

Tags: heroku

Just wondering if there is any risk that I could prematurely share a website with the world by uploading to heroku for testing purposes?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they do.  They are a website on the web just like any other.

Google will still respect a robots.txt file etc, and you could apply htaccess auth to your application to stop people getting in if needed.

Comment: Thanks for that Neil. Felt silly asking, but will definitely delete app once tested. I will have a look at htaccess auth as well.